# Directive Scope is not coming through controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are having an issue in getting the scope into the controller and downgrading the angular version to 1.5.3 is actually fixing it up.

Can someone help us with what is wrong with angular 1.6.3 or if this needs to be done any differently?

Please ignore any syntax errors as the actual code has none

```
// Simple Directive 

var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateURL: 'sometemplate.html',
    scope: {
        text: '@'
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'someCtrl',
    controller: 'someController'
}

// someController.js

var self = this;

self.text //this comes back as undefined which is the issue

sometemplate.html 

{{someCtrl.text}} // this works
```

so in short the scope is working for the template but is not avaialble in controller.

For the same if we rollback the version from 1.6.3 to 1.5.3 it starts to work..

Also tried changing the bind to controller to a object with same fields as scope but it doesnt work with 1.6.3.

are we missing something??

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are binding to controller. When bindToController is set to true, all the scope values being inherited are bound to the variable provided under controllerAs.  Look for the value on the injected $scope on the provided name of someCtrl.

Comment: hey - i have tried that. someCtrl in the scope is also coming back as empty. I am trying to see if there is a different way to do it. and why it works in with 1.5.3 and 1.6.3

Comment: make a plunkr and I'll mess with it.